# Can I insert an entire row using one key-value array?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using php and mysqli. Can I do something like this:

```
$insertObject = new stdClass();
$insertObject->column_1 = "foo";
$insertObject->column_2 = "bar";
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `my_table` (`all_columns_at_once`) VALUES ('$insertobject')");
```

The reason I'm asking is because I'm using a webservice to let our apps access our database. One of our apps needs to insert a whole bunch of fields at once. There are about 30 columns in the table that need to be filled and to avoid having to fetch them all as separate values and create a giant query (which will be a pain to adjust in the future) I'd like to just send a json string to the webservice, create an object out of it and insert the entire object at once.

Comment: How is the data stored? In an array? Comma separated? One value per field?

Comment: @GaryHayes It will have to be implemented first, so whatever is easiest to use. My preference would be a simple json string.

Comment: Have you looked into any ORM libraries such as http://www.doctrine-project.org/ ?

Comment: @AndyRobinson It's just for one function, I'd like to avoid using third party libraries for such a trivial thing. If it's very hard to do without a library, then it's not worth the time anyway.

Comment: What about adding a toArray() method to your object and then creating a simple function to generate the SQL dynamically perhaps via array_keys() and array_values?

Comment: Well, if you've yet to implement it, I'd consider using an encoded array. Decode array on use and iterate with foreach.

Comment: A small function using `call_user_func_array()`, `get_object_vars` & `mysql::bind_param` would do the trick AFAIK?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas guys, I think I'm going with @Andy's suggestion. It seems pretty easy to implement, easy to expand on and time is a factor.